# If I can't use $apply() on $scope() what can I use?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In AngularJS, everywhere I read it says that you almost rarely ever call $apply() yourself, as it's a bad idea somehow (usually left unclear.)

Can someone explain to me:

1. How to avoid using $apply() but still updating variables in $scope
2. Why is it so terribly bad to call $apply()
3. And how to determine when it is OK to use $apply()

Example code:

```
app.controller('ExampleController', function($scope) {

    $scope.variableForView = 'Initial value';

    // for demonstration purposes
    someEvent.on('eventFire', function(data) {

        $scope.variableForView = data;
        $scope.$apply(); // ???

    });

});
```

Comment: Do no bind events manually, use angular event handlers, you wont end up triggering digest cycle manually then.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, `$apply` runs the `$digest`. If `$digest` is already running, then you can't initiate another `$digest`.

I have created the method `$safeApply()`, that I add to the prototype of my `$rootScope` inside the `run()` commend:

```
// $safeApply only calls $apply if $digest is not running
// Otherwise, will only call back fn()
Object.getPrototypeOf($rootScope).$safeApply = function(fn)
{
    var phase = $rootScope.$$phase;

    if (phase == '$apply' || phase == '$digest') {
       if (_.isFunction(fn)) fn();
    } else {
       this.$apply(fn);
     }
};
```

This basically makes sure you are not already in the `$digest` cycle before calling `$apply`. If you are (which means it is not necessary to call `$apply`, I just run the the `fn`. I never use `$apply()` and always use `$safeApply()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the binding methods angular provides.  Then it will do the `$apply` for you.  The reason they say manually `$apply`ing is bad is because you should be using the angular methods for binding and if you are not using them and having to `$apply` manually, then your doing something wrong.

```
app.controller('ExampleController', function($scope) {

    $scope.variableForView = 'Initial value';

    // for demonstration purposes
    $scope.$on('someEventFire', function(data) {
        $scope.variableForView = data;
    });

});
```

Also see https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/When-to-use-%24scope.%24apply%28%29